# Is it possible to save Avro serialized records in Parquet format?

Tags: apache-spark, avro, parquet

I'm making a job that serializes some records in Avro format (using `org.apache.spark.sql.avro.functions.to_avro`) and then saves them in Parquet format. But I'm getting some errors saying there are malformed records when reading from the parquet format.
When I store those avro serialized records in kafka and then use `from_avro` to read them there is no problem.

I'm thinking it is because the Avro serialized records should be saved as avro format instead but I'm not 100% sure about this.

Comment: Could you had a code snipper showing exactly what you are trying to do. A reproducible example is always very helpful.

Comment: If you have a proper Spark Dataframe schema, the input and output formats do not need to match